# How to set an empty value in a lift select element?

Tags: scala, lift

I am trying to set an empty value (as a first choice) in a lift select element:

```
SHtml.select(("", "") :: (MyObject.findAll(By(MyObject.creator, User.currentUser.open_!.id))), ...
```

However it gives me this error:

```
error: type mismatch;
found: List[(String, java.lang.Object)]
required: Seq[(String, String)]
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking it up into a few steps.

```
val choices:Seq[(String,String)] = ("","") :: (all the rest of your options here)

scala> ("","")::List(("c","d"), ("d","e"))  
res8: List[(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)] = List((,), (c,d), (d,e))
```

Then use that `choices` var as input to the `SHtml.select` method.  There's nothing preventing this approach from working.

Answer (score 0):

Example of I82Much has problems with compiling and shows errors.
I have modified his answer and have no problems. Tested.

define variable:

```
val choices = List(("",""), ("S", "Storage"))
```

and then use it

```
"strType" -> SHtml.select(choices, Empty, storage.strType(_), "class" -> "smallInputSelect"),
```